# UIButtonの外枠のプロパティ値をアニメーションで変更する方法について

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

現在、ボタンの選択時の動作について作成しています。

[やりたいこと]
あるボタンを選択したときに、UIButtonの各layerプロパティ値をアニメーションで変更したいと考えています。

[現状]
以下のコードで実行したところ、delay、animateWithDurationをまたずに、プロパティ値が設定されてしまいます。

[環境]
XCode 6.0.1
iOS   6.0以上

こちらの現象の解決方法について、ご教示いただけるとありがたいです。

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5f // アニメーション速度2.5秒
                      delay:1.0f // 1秒後にアニメーション
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     //ボタンA
                     buttonA.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
                     buttonA.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
                     buttonA.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0f;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // アニメーション終了時
                     NSLog(@"アニメーション終了");
                 }];
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Layer-Backed View`なiOSだと混同しがちですが、`UIView`に対するアニメーションと、`CALayer`に対するアニメーションは別物です。

`animateWithDuration:`系統のメソッドは、`UIView`に対するアニメーションを行います。このとき、操作可能なプロパティには制限があります。[iOS View プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/ViewPG_iPhoneOS.pdf)より、「アニメーション化の対象」の章を参照ください。

`CALayer`の`borderColor`などに対してアニメーションを行う場合は、[Core Animation プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/CoreAnimation_guide.pdf)より、レイヤベースのアニメーションを記述する必要があります。

例えば、以下のようなコードになります。

```
CABasicAnimation *borderColorAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderColor"];
borderColorAnimation.fromValue = (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
borderColorAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

CABasicAnimation *borderWidthAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderWidth"];
borderWidthAnimation.fromValue = @0.f;
borderWidthAnimation.toValue = @1.f;

CABasicAnimation *cornerRadiusAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
cornerRadiusAnimation.fromValue = @0.f;
cornerRadiusAnimation.toValue = @25.f;

CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animationGroup.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1.0;
animationGroup.duration = 2.5;
animationGroup.repeatCount = 1;
animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animationGroup.animations = @[borderColorAnimation, borderWidthAnimation, cornerRadiusAnimation];
[self.button.layer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:@"animation"];
```

Comment: 貴重なご説明ありがとうございました。無事、アニメーションを付けることができました。ご説明いただいたレファレンスについて、また確認したいと思います。本当にありがとうございました。